# NULL values in a table if they're not found in a cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I am trying to:

1. Create a cursor that gets all the current prices of items in a store.
2. I bulk collect the cursor and loop upserting by using MERGE statement into STORE_INVENTORY table.
3. Now I want to NULL out the PRICE column in the STORE_INVENTORY table that are not in the cursor.

How can step 3 be done? I can do step 1 and 2 already as I have already updated or inserted the items that are pulled from the cursor.

Here is some example data:

There are three source tables where it is updated by an external party. My objective is to take these three sources of data and merge it into a singular table.

**SOURCE TABLES**

```
ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  ITEM_ID | TYPE 
  0       |  Kitchen
  1       |  Bath

ITEM_MANIFEST
  ITEM_ID | ORIGIN
  0       | USA
  1       | CHINA

ITEM_PRICE
  ITEM_ID | PRICE
  0       | 3.99
  1       | 2.99
```

**DESTINATION TABLE**

```
STORE_INVENTORY 
  ITEM_ID | TYPE    | ORIGIN | PRICE
  0       | Kitchen | CHINA  | 3.99
  8       | Bath    | USA    | 2.99
```

So after I execute the SQL Procedure the source tables to be upserted into STORE_INVENTORY and have any items that are not in the source table to have the price nulled. I know how to do the Upsert portion, but I do not know how to NULL out the price for items that already exist in the STORE_INVENTORY table.

**Expected Output**

```
STORE_INVENTORY
0 | Kitchen | USA   | 3.99
1 | Bath    | China | 2.99
8 | Bath    | USA   | NULL
```

I know from this example that I could just look for if the ITEM_ID is not in the any of the SOURCE_TABLES then null it out, but what if there were more complicated logic that determined what items to pull from the source tables? (Which is why I want to use a cursor) I trying to figure out if I can compare against what is NOT IN the cursor?

Comment: Why do you want a cursor?

Comment: @jarlh I believe I need to use a cursor for upserting into the STORE_PRICE table. I would be getting product information from multiple tables.

Comment: how about a simplified example of your table structure?

Comment: @kevinsky I added it. I basically made up this example. But I am basically trying to figure out how to NULL out an item's column based on it not being in the cursor.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you've got so far, please? Sounds like you ought to be able to do it all in one MERGE statement, rather than trying to reinvent database joins like you're currently doing with your row-by-row approach. Create table scripts, sample input data and expected output would be appreciated too

Comment: As for getting the NULL values, sounds like you need to do a left (or possibly full) outer join on the STORE_PRICE to the query used in the cursor, and then use that as the source data for the MERGE statement.

Comment: What is the purpose behind your question? Is this just for Oracle practice, or do you have a real-world (or homework) requirement to fulfil? Because if it's the latter, then it should be easy enough to mock up sample tables and data to demonstrate what you're trying to do. In fact, even if it's a made up scenario, you ought to be able to mock up the details for us.

Comment: (By providing us with all the details needed for us to recreate your tables, you give us a much better chance of being able to help you. I swear I'm not asking for this info just to make your life more difficult; it's kind of akin to turning up at a garage to ask them to order you a new wing mirror for your car, without telling them what make or model of car it is!)

Comment: @Boneist Understood. I have added example data I am trying to achieve. I hope this helps. Thank you for the constructive feedback. I am still fairly new to PL/SQL so I am not the best at wording what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to learn it for work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suspected, this just requires a single MERGE statement:

```
create table item_description 
as
select 0 item_id, 'Kitchen' type from dual union all
select 1 item_id, 'Bath' type from dual;

create table item_manifest
as
select 0 item_id, 'USA' origin from dual union all
select 1 item_id, 'CHINA' origin from dual;

create table item_price
as
select 0 item_id, 3.99 price from dual union all
select 1 item_id, 2.99 price from dual;

create table store_inventory
as
select 0 item_id, 'Kitchen' type, 'CHINA' origin, 3.99 price from dual union all
select 8 item_id, 'Bath' type, 'USA' origin, 2.99 price from dual;

select * from store_inventory;

   ITEM_ID TYPE    ORIGIN      PRICE
---------- ------- ------ ----------
         0 Kitchen CHINA        3.99
         8 Bath    USA          2.99

merge into store_inventory tgt
using (select coalesce(id.item_id, si.item_id) item_id,
              coalesce(id.type, si.type) type,
              coalesce(im.origin, si.origin) origin,
              ip.price
       from   item_description id
              inner join item_manifest im on (id.item_id = im.item_id)
              inner join item_price ip on (id.item_id = ip.item_id)
              full outer join store_inventory si on (si.item_id = id.item_id)) src
  on (src.item_id = tgt.item_id)
when matched then
  update set tgt.type = src.type,
             tgt.origin = src.origin,
             tgt.price = src.price
when not matched then
  insert (tgt.item_id, tgt.type, tgt.origin, tgt.price)
  values (src.item_id, src.type, src.origin, src.price);

commit;

select * from store_inventory;

   ITEM_ID TYPE    ORIGIN      PRICE
---------- ------- ------ ----------
         0 Kitchen USA          3.99
         8 Bath    USA              
         1 Bath    CHINA        2.99
```

All I did was first of all write the select statement that produced the joined list of item_id, type, origin and price from the source tables.

Once I had that, it was then just a case of doing a full outer join onto the store_inventory, to make sure that all rows, be they new or existing rows would be displayed.

Then I did a coalesce on the item_id, type and origin columns, so that if the row exists only in the store_inventory table, we'd still see those details populated, but I kept the price from the source rows - which if it didn't exist would be null.

Then it's just a matter of merging the results of that query back into the store_inventory table.

If you are ever in doubt about how to merge/update/insert rows into a table, see if you can first write a select statement that procduces the results that you are after. It's often just a matter of taking that statement and plugging it into the relevant merge/update/insert statement.

Comment: wow that's pretty great. I believe that is what I was looking for. I will try to incorporate this logic. I have not used the coalesce function before. Thanks for your patience in helping me!

Comment: Absolutely no problem at all *{:-) I used Coalesce over NVL simply because a) it's more flexible than NVL - you can have more than two arguments and b) COALESCE stops evaluating the arguments at the first non-null value. NVL always evaluates both. Whilst using NVL wouldn't be a problem in this case, it's best to start good habits early *{:-)

Comment: I believe I might have mislead you on the simplicity of the problem. I would like to keep this question as this was a great learning experience. However, could you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516372/null-values-not-found-in-cursor it is slightly more complex I believe as you cannot directly join on each of the source tables to the destination.