# NULL values not found in cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, merge

I am trying to:

Create a cursor that gets all the current prices of items in a store.
I bulk collect the cursor and loop upserting by using MERGE statement into STORE_INVENTORY table.
Now I want to NULL out the PRICE column in the STORE_INVENTORY table that are not in the cursor.
How can step 3 be done? I can do step 1 and 2 already as I have already updated or inserted the items that are pulled from the cursor.

Here is some example data:

There are three source tables where it is updated by an external party. My objective is to take these three sources of data and merge it into a singular table.

```
SOURCE TABLES

ITEM_TYPES
  DESC_ID | TYPE 
  A       |  Kitchen
  B       |  Bath

ITEM_MANIFEST

  LOC_ID  | ORIGIN
  U       | USA
  C       | CHINA

ITEM_PRICE

  ITEM_ID | PRICE | DESC_ID | LOC_ID | DATE
  0       | 3.99  |  A      |  U     | 9/11/2015
  1       | 2.99  |  B      |  C     | 9/11/2015
  2       | 1.99  |  A      |  U     | 9/05/2015
```

DESTINATION TABLE

```
STORE_INVENTORY 
  ITEM_ID | TYPE    | ORIGIN | PRICE
  0       | Kitchen | CHINA  | 3.99
  8       | Bath    | USA    | 2.99
```

So after I execute the SQL Procedure that has a date as a parameter. It will only pull from ITEM_PRICE if it's after the given date.

If execute the procedure with the passed in date 9/10/2015

Expected Output

```
STORE_INVENTORY
0 | Kitchen | USA   | 3.99
1 | Bath    | China | 2.99
8 | Bath    | USA   | NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, something like this, then?

```
drop table item_description;
drop table item_manifest;
drop table item_price;
drop table store_inventory;

create table item_description 
as
select 'A' desc_id, 'Kitchen' type from dual union all
select 'B' desc_id, 'Bath' type from dual;

create table item_manifest
as
select 'U' loc_id, 'USA' origin from dual union all
select 'C' loc_id, 'CHINA' origin from dual;

create table item_price
as
select 0 item_id, 3.99 price, 'A' desc_id, 'U' loc_id, to_date('11/09/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
select 1 item_id, 2.99 price, 'B' desc_id, 'C' loc_id, to_date('11/09/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
select 2 item_id, 1.99 price, 'A' desc_id, 'U' loc_id, to_date('05/09/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual;

create table store_inventory
as
select 0 item_id, 'Kitchen' type, 'CHINA' origin, 3.99 price from dual union all
select 8 item_id, 'Bath' type, 'USA' origin, 2.99 price from dual;

select * from store_inventory;

   ITEM_ID TYPE    ORIGIN      PRICE
---------- ------- ------ ----------
         0 Kitchen CHINA        3.99
         8 Bath    USA          2.99

select coalesce(ip.item_id, si.item_id) item_id,
              coalesce(id.type, si.type) type,
              coalesce(im.origin, si.origin) origin,
              ip.price
       from   item_description id
              inner join item_price ip on (id.desc_id = ip.desc_id and ip.dt > to_date('10/09/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')) -- use a parameter for the date here
              inner join item_manifest im on (ip.loc_id = im.loc_id)
              full outer join store_inventory si on (si.item_id = ip.item_id);

   ITEM_ID TYPE    ORIGIN      PRICE
---------- ------- ------ ----------
         0 Kitchen USA          3.99
         8 Bath    USA              
         1 Bath    CHINA        2.99

merge into store_inventory tgt
using (select coalesce(ip.item_id, si.item_id) item_id,
              coalesce(id.type, si.type) type,
              coalesce(im.origin, si.origin) origin,
              ip.price
       from   item_description id
              inner join item_price ip on (id.desc_id = ip.desc_id and ip.dt > to_date('10/09/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')) -- use a parameter for the date here
              inner join item_manifest im on (ip.loc_id = im.loc_id)
              full outer join store_inventory si on (si.item_id = ip.item_id)) src
  on (src.item_id = tgt.item_id)
when matched then
  update set tgt.type = src.type,
             tgt.origin = src.origin,
             tgt.price = src.price
when not matched then
  insert (tgt.item_id, tgt.type, tgt.origin, tgt.price)
  values (src.item_id, src.type, src.origin, src.price);

commit;

select * from store_inventory;

   ITEM_ID TYPE    ORIGIN      PRICE
---------- ------- ------ ----------
         0 Kitchen USA          3.99
         8 Bath    USA              
         1 Bath    CHINA        2.99
```

Obviously, your procedure would have an input parameter of DATE datatype to pass into the query, and your query would use the parameter, rather than a hardcoded date like I did in my example. E.g. `ip.dt > p_cutoff_date`

> I can do step 1 and 2 already as I have already updated or inserted
>   the items that are pulled from the cursor.

Hmm. These steps seem unnecessary - why not do them as part of the MERGE statement? What does the store_inventory table look like before you do your insert/update from the cursor? Also, what is the cursor you're using to do this?

Comment: oh, love the simple sample table creation.  I still think the whole thing is way simpler than it is made out to be, but without any more code or details about starting contents for STORE_INVENTORY from OP I can't be bothered.

Comment: Yeah; the whole "I'm using a cursor" thing is a major red flag! Set based processing FTW!

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you do a date-limited subselect of ITEM_PRICE.PRICE, after pulling in the TYPE and ORIGIN via the main join to ITEM_PRICE, without limiting on date?

i.e. something like.

```
select ITEM_ID, TYPE, ORIGIN
/* not selecting PRICE in the main join */
,(select PRICE from ITEM_PRICE where your join conditions 
and DATE >= your param)
from ITEM_TYPES, ITEM_MANIFEST, ITEM_PRICE
where your join conditions, but no criteria on DATE
```

Sorry, would be clearer and easier to type up if you had provided your existing query.

From re-reading your question, I am unsure if you are inserting only 2 rows but want to get 3.  Or if you have 3 rows, but you want to NULL out the missing price.

If the target table already has the 3 rows, then, instead of doing a CURSOR based approach (which can be slow on high volumes and is fussy to write), why not do an UPDATE instead, with DATE as a criteria?  The NULL will be assigned to price if there is no match, that's how UPDATEs work.

```
  UPDATE STORE_INVENTORY set PRICE
  = (select PRICE from ITEM_PRICE where your join conditions 
  and DATE >= your param)
```